# Mediaelement.js binding spacebar and messing with chat client

Tags: mediaelement.js

I have integrated mediaelement.js and its working fine but now that I have integrated chat client on the website I am facing a weird issue. When I press a "spacebar" inside the chatbox of the chat client it gets bind to mediaelement.js  and video(being played on the page) stops.

Issue: I am not able to type space inside the chat client because it gets bind to media.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured that there is an option:

```
enableKeyboard: false
```

which should be set to false. By default its true. once you set it to false all is good. But I think by default it should be set to false.